# Scrapy crawl in while loop

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

Trying to head my head around the whole twisted reactor / scrapy crawler wiring.

What I need is something like this:

```
while True:
    urls = get_latest_urls()

    crawl(MySpider(urls))
    ## block until crawl is complete ##

    mark_urls_as_crawled()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

and have this script running indefinitely.

How do I go about doing this? Thanks!

---

**Solved**

Managed to get the functionality I wanted by getting rid of the while loop and using callbacks.

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings=get_project_settings())
crawl()
reactor.run()

def crawl():
    d = process.crawl(MySpider(get_latest_urls()))
    d.addBoth(crawl_done)

def crawl_done():
    mark_urls_as_crawled()
    crawl()
```

Comment: I have the impression that you might be interested in https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-deltafetch too.